# Excel VBA - How to add multiple statements in If Then - If (Condition 1) Then (Close window) and (End Sub)

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have created a macro where it copies certain cells and pastes it in a new window(Excel). I am trying to add an If Then statement in the Macro where after pasting the data, if a particular cell is blank (lets say A2), I want the macro to close that window and end the Macro. I have tried the below coding but it gives me ***Compile Error: Block if without End IF***.

```
Windows("Data.xlsx").Activate
Rows("13:18").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Data Paste.xlsx").Activate

Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


If ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = "" Then
ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
End If

Range("A2:A6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Just to be more clear, what i need is; first Rows 13:18 to be copied from "DATA.xlsx" and pasted in "Data Paste.xlsx" and then to check if the Cell A2 is empty and if so to close window "Data Paste.xlsx" and stop the Macro from Running. If the A2 cell is not empty I want the Macro to continue without closing the window and continue with the bellow code:

```
Range("A2:A6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
'Rest of the code
```

Please find me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, instead of `End Sub` using `Exit Sub` works just perfect!!

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


If ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = "" Then
ActiveWindow.Close
Exit Sub
End If

Range("A2:A6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to correct multiple syntax errors, like shown in the sample Excel VBA `Sub` shown below :

```
Sub CopyClose()
    Windows("Data.xlsx").Activate
    Rows("13:18").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Data Paste.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ' check for the condition, and close the window and exit sub if true
    ' otherwise, execute the next line
    If ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = "" Then
        ActiveWindow.Close
    Else
        Range("A2:A6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: I am looking for the Macro to close the window and stop the macro if the Value on A2 = " ". If the value is not " " then I want the Macro to continue running with rest of the code.

Comment: You have to clarify the requirements: "A2" in which Workbook (you have two - origin "Data.xlsx" and destination "Data Paste.xlsx"). Thanks and regards,

Comment: If A2 in "Data Paste.xlsx" = " " Then I want to close  "Data Paste.xlsx" and Stop Macro. FYI - Macro is Running from the window "Data.xlsx"

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Please refer to the answer modified as per your requirements. Best regards

Comment: I am not sure if my question is unclear..what i need is.. first Rows 13:18 to be copied from "DATA.xlsx" and pasted in "Data Paste.xlsx" and then to check if the Cell A2 is empty and if so to close window "Data Paste.xlsx" and stop the Macro from Running. If the A2 cell is not empty i want the Macro to continue without closing the window and continue with the bellow code: 
Range("A2:A6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

Comment: OK, I am modifying the code for the last time. Please mark the answer accepted, and should you still have more questions, please post them separately. Thanks and regards,

Comment: Sorry, but the macro doesn't end, it only closes the active window (Data Paste.xlsx) and the Macro continues with rest of the code after End If.

Comment: Sorry, it sounds a bit confusing. After closing that window the execution moves to the line End Sub, which means ending it. I guess, you have to familiarize yourself a bit with Excel VBA and modify the rest of your code. I am closing this comments thread. Best regards,

Comment: The problem is I have few more lines of codes after End If before End Sub.. so i want VBA to stop the Macro if the condition is true if not even after end if, it still needs to continue with other codes

Comment: Then put that "other code" which you've mentioned now in Else condition. Please mark this answer accepted and post any other questions separately. Rgds,

Comment: Thanks Alex, your code works just fine, but i wanted multiple statements in 'Then' to stop the macro as i wanted to write the rest of the code ending the If statement. I think the below answer i have posted works pretty well for that.

Comment: You are welcome. Sure thing, both solutions should work just fine. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

End Sub should be Exit Sub. Exit terminates early, End means the natural end of the code.

```
 If ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = "" Then
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Exit Sub
 End If
```